# Identify duplicate rows allowing for x mismatches and ignoring NA

Tags: r

I have a question or actually 2 related ones.

I have a data frame (rows >10.000, cols >100). I would like to identify rows that are duplicates. I am familiar with duplicated() and unique(). However, these will only find exact duplicates. So if I would have a row with 3 values `1 5 8` this would not be considered a duplicate of a row with the values `1 NA 8`.

The 1st question is, how can I find duplicated rows but ignore NA/treat NA as a wildcard? Ideally, I would create groups of these duplicated rows.

Take the following example data:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c(1,2,2,1,2,1,7,1), 
                 "y"=c(5,3,3,NA,NA,5,8,5), 
                 "z" =  c(8,8,8,8,8,8,9,NA))

df  
  x  y  z  
---------
1 1  5  8  
2 2  3  8  
3 2  3  8  
4 1 NA  8  
5 2 NA  8  
6 1  5  8  
7 1  8  8  
8 1  5 NA
```

I realise ignoring NAs would lead to some problems here. For example we have in row 1: 1 5 8 and in row 7: 1 8 8. Where would we group row 4: 1 NA 8? It could match with both row 1 and row 4 and thus belong to either group. So maybe one way to deal with this is to copy that row 4 and assign both groups. I hope this makes sense...

So the result would be:

```
  x  y  z group
---------------
1 1  5  8     1
2 2  3  8     2
3 2  3  8     2
4 1 NA  8     1
5 1 NA  8     3
6 2 NA  8     2
7 1  5  8     1
8 1  8  8     3
9 1  5 NA     1
```

My 2nd question would be, how can I allow for 1 (or more) mismatches? If I would allow for 1 potential mismatch, row 7: 1 8 8 would be grouped together with row 1: 1 5 8

So the result would be:

```
  x  y  z group
---------------
1 1  5  8     1
2 2  3  8     2
3 2  3  8     2
4 1 NA  8     1
5 1 NA  8     2
6 2 NA  8     1
7 2 NA  8     2
8 1  5  8     1
9 1  8  8     1
10 1  5 NA     1
```

I realise this becomes quickly very tricky, but I still hope you can help me on the way!

ps I am familiar with tidyverse so a solution including that is also fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do all these things with base R functions

`sum` and `all` can handle things like this using `na.rm = TRUE`:

```r
vec1 <- c(1, 5, 8)
vec2 <- c(1, NA, 8)
vec3 <- c(1, 11, 8)

vec1 == vec2
#> [1] TRUE   NA TRUE

# Compare vectors, ignoring missing values
all(vec1 == vec2, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
all(vec1 == vec3, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE

# Counting mismatches, checking they're below a threshold
sum(vec1 != vec2, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 0
sum(vec1 != vec3, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 1
sum(vec1 != vec3, na.rm = TRUE) <= 1
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that in the latter case, you're counting mismatches and ignoring `NA`s. To count both, you'd need to `sum(vec1 != vec3, is.na(vec1 == vec3), na.rm = TRUE)`

### Comparing each row with every other row

You can use nested `apply` to compare every column with every other column, returning a (functionally) triangular matrix which indexes the matches

```r
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1, 1,NA,5,1),
                 v2 = c(2,NA,1,NA,1,2),
                 v3 = c(3,3, 1,NA,3,8),
                 v4 = c(4,4, 4,NA,4,4))

df
#>   v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1  1  2  3  4
#> 2  1 NA  3  4
#> 3  1  1  1  4
#> 4 NA NA NA NA
#> 5  5  1  3  4
#> 6  1  2  8  4


apply(df, 1, function(x){
  apply(df, 1, function(y){
    sum(x != y, na.rm = TRUE) <=1
  })
}) -> matchMatrix

matchMatrix[upper.tri(matchMatrix)] <- NA 

matchMatrix
#>       [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]  TRUE   NA    NA   NA    NA   NA
#> [2,]  TRUE TRUE    NA   NA    NA   NA
#> [3,] FALSE TRUE  TRUE   NA    NA   NA
#> [4,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE    NA   NA
#> [5,] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   NA
#> [6,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I implement this for a larger data frame? I want to compare each row with every other row. Ideally, I would also have an identifier for matching groups?

Comment: an 'identifier for matching groups' is hard to define. In my example, col `v2` matches every other col, but those cols don't match with each other. If we were comparing cols that were completely unique, we could use the identical values of the cols to form groups. But here those rules can't be applied. To put it another way: in this framework every column has its own group, but some columns are the only columns in their group.

Comment: I think your example actually compares columns vs columns. But this is just a simple matter of changing the 2 in the apply functions into a 1. I really like this part `sum(x != y, na.rm = TRUE) <=1 #ignore NA, allow one mismatch` so simple and elegant...why didn't I think of that! I am struggling a bit with converting the matchesMatrix again into something I can work with. As my 'real' datafile is much larger I expect to get a very very big matchesMatrix so then I would need to export the TRUE matches again as a list or something... anyway, I might post a new question when I get to that point!